# Chi-squared test on the observed vs expected frequencies of elements taken pairwise

Tags: chi-squared-test, independence

I have the following problem. I have a total of $N$ observations, and for each of these, I am evaluating absence (0) /presence (1) of a given factor. Let's call these factors $A$, $B$, $C$ and $D$.

I am only interested in the cases for which presence is evaluated for exactly two factors. Specifically, I am interested into testing whether a particular case, ${A=1, B=0, C=1, D=0}$ is statistically observed more or less than  expected by chance, given the individual frequencies of the four factors in that set.

Let's consider the following example in R, where `Nobs` is the number of observations for each combination of factors, pairwise:

```r
df <- data.frame(A = c(0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1),
                 B = c(0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1),
                 C = c(1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0),
                 D = c(1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0),
                 Nobs = c(613, 209, 298, 280, 382, 147))
```

Is `Nobs = 382` different from the random expectation based on the frequency of occurrence of $A$ and $C$ separately?

I assume this can be done with `chisq.test(x = c(613, 209, 298, 280, 382, 147), p = vector_of_expected_frequencies)`, and this should be a very easy task, but I am struggling getting the expected frequencies.

I would say that in my data set, $p(A)$, $p(B)$, $p(C)$ and $p(D)$ are the following:

```r
pA <- dplyr::filter(df, A==1) %>% .$Nobs %>% sum() %>% `/`(2*N)
pB <- dplyr::filter(df, B==1) %>% .$Nobs %>% sum() %>% `/`(2*N)
pC <- dplyr::filter(df, C==1) %>% .$Nobs %>% sum() %>% `/`(2*N)
pD <- dplyr::filter(df, D==1) %>% .$Nobs %>% sum() %>% `/`(2*N)
```

Made this way, $p(A)+p(B)+p(C)+p(D)=1$ as expected, but then, the probability of all combinations pairwise will result in probabilities that do not sum to $1$, and are therefore not usable for the test. In fact, they add to a much lower number.

```r
df %>%
  dplyr::mutate(tmpA = ifelse(A==0, 1, pA),
                tmpB = ifelse(B==0, 1, pB),
                tmpC = ifelse(C==0, 1, pC),
                tmpD = ifelse(D==0, 1, pD)) %>%
  dplyr::mutate(prod = tmpA*tmpB*tmpC*tmpD) %>%
  .$prod %>%
  sum()
```

There must be something trivial I am missing here, any help is appreciated.